# getline() not waiting for input inside switch...case (C++)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get input from the user using getline().

The following code works fine. It waits for the user to type the file name and stores it in fileName.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string inputFile();

int main() 
{
    string fileName;
    cout << "Enter the name of the file including the path" << endl;            
    getline(cin, fileName);

    return 0;
}
```

However, this code does not work fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string inputFile();

int main() 
{
    int option;

    cout << "Enter option number" << endl;
    cin >> option;

    switch (option)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            string fileName;
            cout << "Enter the name of the file including the path" << endl;            
            getline(cin, fileName);
            break;
        }
        case 2:
            cout << "You chose option 2";
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "You chose option 3";
            break;
        default:
            cout << "value unknown";
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

After the user enters 1 and the program enters the switch...case, the user is again asked for the file name. But, this time the program does not wait for a response.

Why is getline() not working the way it would outside the switch...case structure?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`cin` leaves the newline character (`\n`) in the stream. `cin.ignore()` extracts and discards characters. It can be used to flush the `cin` until `\n` is reached.

So, the solution is to add `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` , before the 2nd call to `getline(cin, fileName);`
Also add `cin.clear()` to remove the error flag on `cin`

Example:

```
case 1:
    {
        std::string fileName;
        std::cout << "Enter the name of the file including the path" << std::endl; 
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        getline(std::cin, fileName);
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be, that you are reading the number of the case via >> into the integer variable. By doing that, the newline produced by the enter key is still in the buffer. Now getline tries to read from the input stream and instantly receives a newline. 
And because it only reads upon the next newline, it exits.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with the `switch`-statement! Instead, it has to do with mixing formatted input (using `operator>>()`) and unformatted input (in this case `std::getline()`): the formatted input stops reading as soon as a character doesn't match the format. When reading an integer, it stops as soon as a non-digit is found. That is, any newline entered after the number will be stuck in the stream and `std::getline()` will happily take this newline as an opportunity to stop its input.

When switching between formatted and unformatted input, you normally want to get rid of whitespaces. For example, you could use

```
if (std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, fileName)) { ... }
```

to first skip any whitespace, then attempt to read `fileName` and, if this is successful, process the input (input always needs to be checked for success).

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing formatted input and line input on a single stream. This is a bad idea, use either formatted input `operator>>` or line input `std::getline()` never both on the same stream.

This is basically because of the way white space is handled. In this case you are leaving a `\n` character on the input when you read the option.

```
cin >> option;
```

This reads the option, but leaves anything after the option (after the integer) on the input stream (including the `\n` character). Thus the next use of std::getline() simply reads upto the `\n` character (which probably gives you zero characters).

Interactive user input is line based.
Especially since the `std::cin` stream is buffered (and thus not flushed until you hit return).

So when I read input from an interactive user I always read a line of text at a time. Then parse this line for what I am looking for.

```
 std::string  optionLine;
 std::getline(std::cin, optionLine);

 int option = boost::lexical_cast<int>(optionLine);
```

Note: You don't need `boost::lexical_cast`, you can achieve the same affect with `std::stringstream` and another variable.

```
 // A simple alternative to boost::lexical_cast
 // Not quite as pedantic as above but you can add more tests as required.
 std::stringstream optionLineStream(optionLine);
 int option;
 if (optionLineStream >> option)
 {
     // reading the option worked.
 }
```

Reading a line at a time and then parsing the input also has the advantage that you never put the input into a bad state and need to reset it (any bad state is set on intermediate `std::stringstream` objects). So fixing erroneous user input is easier.